# I am required to build a program for kiosk in java. i could not find how to use it's pin pad and card reader

Tags: java, kiosk

i am totally new in programming kiosk. 
i have built the program in my computer but i have no idea how to use pin pad and card reader as an input device to my program. the program is not a web based program.

Comment: Well, what is the hardware? Have you checked for documentation with the manufacturer?

Comment: Typically a pin pad will be treated as a keyboard device, and your card reader is either the same or should have an API.

Comment: wincor nixdorf is the hardware. the documentation dont contain programming references in java.